# Issues with header redirect not running when posting session data

Tags: php, xml

Essentially I have a page which prints a form, form is filled out - then user is redirected to a 3rd party payment page (and data sent to 3rd party payment page via xml request). Here is the function which should be working:

```
function redirect_form()
{
  global $pxpay;

  $request = new PxPayRequest();

  $http_host   = getenv("HTTP_HOST");
  $request_uri = getenv("SCRIPT_NAME");
  $server_url  = "http://$http_host";
  #$script_url  = "$server_url/$request_uri"; //using this code before PHP version 4.3.4
  $script_url  = "$server_url$request_uri"; //Using this code after PHP version 4.3.4
  #$script_url = (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, "4.3.4", ">=")) ?"$server_url$request_uri" : "$server_url/$request_uri";

  $MerchantReference = $_REQUEST["Reference"];   
  $StudentName = $_REQUEST["x_name"];
  $Venue = $_REQUEST["x_venue"];
  $Course = $_REQUEST["x_course"];
  $AmountInput = $_REQUEST["x_amount"];
  $Currency = $_REQUEST["x_currency"];
  $Email = $_REQUEST["x_email"];



  #Generate a unique identifier for the transaction
  $TxnId = uniqid("ID");

  #Set PxPay properties
  $request->setMerchantReference($MerchantReference);
  $request->setAmountInput($AmountInput);
  $request->setTxnData1($StudentName);
  $request->setTxnData2($Venue);
  $request->setTxnData3($Course);
  $request->setTxnType("Purchase");
  $request->setCurrencyInput($Currency);
  $request->setEmailAddress($Email);
  $request->setUrlFail($script_url);            # can be a dedicated failure page
  $request->setUrlSuccess($script_url);         # can be a dedicated success page
  $request->setTxnId($TxnId);  

  #The following properties are not used in this case
  # $request->setEnableAddBillCard($EnableAddBillCard);    
  # $request->setBillingId($BillingId);
  # $request->setOpt($Opt);



  #Call makeRequest function to obtain input XML
  $request_string = $pxpay->makeRequest($request);

  #Obtain output XML
  $response = new MifMessage($request_string);

  #Parse output XML
  $url = $response->get_element_text("URI");
  $valid = $response->get_attribute("valid");

   #Redirect to payment page
   header("Location: ".$url);
}
```

This form works perfectly in the sample code when its using $_REQUEST and the form sends perfectly if I comment out the part where each variable is defined - each variable is also a string.

I have done testing with defining the variables as plain text and it still works.

This function is being called by:

```
if (isset($_POST['StudentName'])) { redirect_form(); }
```

The issue is that the page is simply going to a blank page - where is should be going to the payment page.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:- 
PHP Error reporting shows:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/becky/public_html/paymentconfirmation.php:244) in /home/becky/public_html/paymentconfirmation.php on line 288
```

Line 244 is:

```
  $MerchantReference = $_REQUEST["Reference"];
```

Line 288 is the header call:

```
header("Location: ".$url);
```

The thing I dont understand is that this issue only arises if there is already a session started filling the form (WHICH I NEED). If you start your session on this page there is no problem.

Please forgive me if this is a simple problem - I tried to find a similar issue that's been solved but struggled

Comment: You are trying to develop blind! While developing always enable Error Reporting in PHP and you will see what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the script which calls your function is part of a page where the headers and output have already been sent to the browser.

You can only modify the headers after that if you are using output buffering. The error that you are receiving tells me that you're not.

```
<?php

/*
 * Establish output buffer, build output string
 */
ob_start();


/* (YOUR ENTIRE SCRIPT / PAGE GOES HERE) */


/*
 * Send output and flush the buffer
 */
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion, and it's rectified my issue for the header error message. However, when the page which sends the request (for the above page) gets its variables from the session it will not load the page, simply comes up blank, no error messages either. If I start a new session on the page which sends a request, then it loads the payment page perfectly - this is dumbfounding me. what difference does it make where the previous page got its data from - the previous page marks the strings uniquely regardless of how it gets the information.

Thanks for your assistance so far